# perl search substring and comment out all occurances

Tags: perl, search, replace, append

i am realy new to perl, but i have to write a perl script which searchs for string in  file and comment out some lines. The Structure of the text in file looks like the lines below. I have to search for some key-strings e.g "1, 0.75, 0.31, 0"

This is what i want to do...

The following in put

```
start_pos {
string-to-search <1, 0.75, 0.31, 0> #FOUND HERE
}
do {
   a 0.1
   d 0.6
   s 0.325
   r 0.029
   }


start_pos {
other-string<1, 0.71, 0.32, 0>
    }
   do {
   a 0.1
   d 0.6
   s 0.325
   r 0.029
   }

start_pos {
string-to-search <**1, 0.75, 0.31, 0**> #FOUND HERE
}
do {
    a 0.1
    d 0.6
   s 0.325
   r 0.029
   }
```

This out put should be

```
//     start_pos {
//     string-to-search <1, 0.75, 0.31, 0> #FOUND HERE !!!
//     }
//     do {
//        a 0.1
//        d 0.6
//        s 0.325
//        r 0.029
//        }


start_pos {
other-string<1, 0.71, 0.32, 0>
    }
   do {
   a 0.1
   d 0.6
   s 0.325
   r 0.029
   }

//     start_pos {
 //    string-to-search <**1, 0.75, 0.31, 0**> #FOUND HERE !!!
//     }
//     do {
//         a 0.1
//         d 0.6
//        s 0.325
//        r 0.029
//      }
```

I have no problem to find the sub string, but i have no idea how to comment the lines starting from "start_pos" to "}".

Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have always the same number of lines belonging to one entry, you can just pickup the nine lines in an array, as soon as you see `start_pos`.

Then you can search for your string. If it is *not* there print the lines as is. If it *is* there, for all lines replace the beginning of the line `^` with the comment `//` and then print the lines

```
my @entry;

# pickup the lines
# and search for the string

if (found) {
    foreach my $line (@entry) {
        $line =~ s!^!// !;
    }
}

foreach my $line (@entry) {
    print "$line";
}
```

*Update:*

Complete example

```perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @entry;
my $collecting = 0;
my $found = 0;

while (<>) {
    if (m/start_pos/) {
        # begin collecting lines
        $collecting = 1;
    }

    if ($collecting) {
        # test for pattern
        if (m/1, 0\.75, 0\.31, 0/) {
            $found = 1;
        }

        # pickup line
        push @entry, $_;
    } else {
        # if not inside a block, just print the line
        print $_;
    }

    # if 9 lines collected
    if ($#entry == 8) {
        if ($found) {
            # prefix with comments
            foreach my $line (@entry) {
                $line =~ s!^!// !;
            }
        }

        # print the block
        foreach my $line (@entry) {
            print "$line";
        }

        # reset variables for next block
        @entry = ();
        $collecting = $found = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Olaf, thanks for your reply. I have always the same number of lines belonging to one entry and i can find the search string.But i still habe a big problem to add all lines which i have to comment out to an array. I have to make the search in a file and comment out the lines. I can open the file with '+<' mode and can comment out the line containing the search string. How can i find the line before search string and the following lines in one entry ? You have a good idea but i can't realize it :(